# Jenkins Master and Slave configuration linux to AIX

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, aix

Here is my environment.

Jenkins Master - Linux 64bit
slave AIX 32 bit

I have to run a few jobs on Jenkins slave which is on AIX 32 bit. The problem is with launching the slave on AIX. I am unable to launch the slave no matter what version of java i use.

I get the following error when launching the slave. ssh is working fine by the way.

```
jre1.8.0_65/bin/java:cannot execute hudson.util.IOException2: Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:984)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$400(SSHLauncher.java:137)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:725)
at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:706)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination*
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other ways you could try to add a slave

[SSH Slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin)
This initiates a connection from the master using a selected set of credentials

[Swarm Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin)
This needs a plugin on the master which then listens for connections from slave nodes wanting to join. I prefer this one as you can ramp up more slaves without having to change the master